# How many times is midpoint checked in binarySearch to find a value?

Tags: c, algorithm, probability, binary-search

If we assume the value exists and is random, how many times will a midpoint be checked to find the value.  This is for an array of 1 million ints.

For example if the value does not exist, the answer is: log base 2 of 1,000,000 or about 20, every time, as the value is never found.

If the number does exist, how many times on average is the midpoint checked?  Would it still be near to 20, and if so why?

Of course this is an ordered array, and the target value is random.

Per suggestions in comments, all values are unique, i.e. there are not duplicates.

Here is the code:

```
int binarySearch(int array[], int find, int low, int high) {
  while(low <= high) {
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if(array[mid] == find) {
      return mid;
    } else if(array[mid] < find) {
      low = mid + 1;
    } else {
      high = mid - 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251742/discussion-on-question-by-bobby-wang-how-many-times-is-midpoint-checked-in-binar); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> If the number does exist, how many times on average is the midpoint checked?

About *log<sub>2</sub>N - 1* times.

> Would it still be 20, and if so why?

No.  Given the number does exist, some iterations will end early, reducing the non-exist target average, by about *at least 1*.  [@Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391750/how-many-times-is-midpoint-checked-in-binarysearch-to-find-a-value#comment133028303_75391750)

By about *at least 1* is because if the values in the array are not unique  (something not addressed by OP), the steps needed to find go down even further.

Answer (score 1):

> If the number does exist, how many times on average is the midpoint checked? Would it still be near to 20, and if so why?

On average, about 19.  Your binary search organizes the values in the array into a binary tree, where the root is the first midpoint you check.  *Half* of the nodes in a complete binary tree are at the deepest level.  Half of the remaining nodes are at the next deepest level, etc.

The equality check is usually more expensive than it's worth.  I recommend writing your binary search like this:

```
int binarySearch(int array[], int find, int low, int high) {
  while(low < high) {
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    if(array[mid] < find) {
      low = mid + 1;
    } else {
      high = mid;
    }
  }
  return array[low] == find ? low : -1; 
}
```

Comment: 1 / 1,000,000 + 1 / 500,000, + 1 / 250,000 ... 1 / 1 is the probability of hitting the target for each iteration from index 0 to index 19.  This should form and equation.